# Workaround for Tweetdeck not authenticating multiple accounts

Tags: authentication, twitter

I had a really frustrating issue recently with Tweetdeck, a tool to manage multiple twitter accounts. Since we get feedback and support questions on Twitter accounts with our projects, it is MUCH easier to see all the information in one place. That said, I had a recent issue and couldn't find ANY help online. I was able to find and test a workaround though, and have decided since it helped me I should post it here.

First, let me explain the exact issue, so you can see if my solution might work for you **(YES, I already have the answer and posted it below)**

I know my Tweetdeck was working previously (as I had multiple accounts). Since some of the projects were going away, and new ones were starting, I removed the existing ones and started ***trying*** to add the new ones.

The twitter page would come up asking to authenticate, then after typing in the information, I would get a generic "You have been logged into Tweetdeck, please return to the application" in the new window, but when closing it, I would not be logged in on Tweetdeck with the other account (only the original one)

I tried NUMEROUS steps to fix this including some of the following (NONE of these steps worked):
Tried different computers (with different Operating Systems). These included Windows 7 and Linux (Ubuntu 10.04) and more than one browser (Google Chrome, Firefox, etc). I also tried clearing cache, cookies, history, etc.

NOTE: *I also tried to contact both Tweetdeck and Twitter support, neither of which have ever responded to any question I have ever had in years.*

So the initial question was... "***How do I get Tweetdeck to authenticate with other accounts successfully***" with the error "***You have been logged into Tweetdeck, please return to the application***", but the new accounts do not actually authenticate and I cannot use them in Tweetdeck.

Comment: Thanks. I do not understand why everyone is not having this problem. My solution was to log out and into each account, authenticate, and then log into TweetDeck. So inefficient as to render it nearly useless day-to-day.

Answer (score 1):

After extensive attempts to find a way to make my Tweetdeck work once again, I found a workaround that has worked great for me. I am not sure exactly why this works, but I have a feeling it has to do with the difference between the authentication method of just Tweetdeck online vs. the Google Chrome App.

On a whim, I decided to install the actual Google Chrome App plugin (as I was running out of options). Then, when using the app, it succeeded with no problems.

While I have posted an **answer** that **works for me** here, I would appreciate any comments that might give more real information (not guesses) on why this happened. If there is something else I can try so that I am not limited to the Google Chrome App if I want to add new accounts, I would also be happy to try those possible solutions. ***Please make sure to read my question which covers what I have already done.***

*NOTE: Since I have a working workaround, if your solution will take substantial effort, I will probably not try it .*

Comment: After further research, I believe this has to do with the call to open a new window and authenticate with twitter when using Tweetdeck in a webpage only. When using the Tweetdeck Google Chrome application, it appears to open a standard size page (that doesn't operate the same as the popup). If anyone working with Twitter or Tweetdeck development sees this, please correct. I am not the only one having this type of issue.